# opening and writing to files in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Am writing a simple application which can write a to pdf,doc,xls and access files. so far it can write to word.i also want it to be able to navigate a hard disk and open these files using filters.
i was using this code to write to the files

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, TextBox1.Text, False)

how can i write to pdf and access files and also navigate and open files using openFileDialog?

Comment: This question is way too big for a single question and pretty scant on the details needed to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using System.IO for writting to files.  Read the documentation on StreamWriter.  It is very straight forward.  One of the constructors for streamwriter accepts a string representation of the path to the file, and overloads allow you to specify a FileMode enumeration value.  Normally you will use FileMode.OpenOrCreate when writting to the file.

OpenFileDialog is also straightforward.  Create an instance and access the selected file property to get a string representation of the path.  Use the static File.Exists("path") to check that a valid path was returned, then use the give path to open the file with a StreamReader.

There is more than one way to skin a cat here because static oriented FileInfo and DirectoryInfo are provided in System.IO, and there are the corresponding File and Directory classes which must be instantiated.

The use of these classes is very straightforward so I'm not going to sit here and type you example code but that should get you started.

As far as creating PDF and XLS files, I am assuming that you already have raw bytes that are in the correct format for those file types?  If not, I can't help you there off hand.  There are no Formatters in the .NET Framework that will convert ASCII or Unicode strings to a format that is acceptable for PDF or XLS that I am aware of.  You are going to either need to dig into the specifics of those file formats or find a third party utility that will format your raw bytes or text into something those specifications.

If you are recieving the PDF and XLS data in the raw already properly formatted just use BinaryWriter to create the new file and write the raw array of bytes.